# Return unique/distinct values with Realm query

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, realm

I have a `Message/RLMObject` model that has a `NSString *jabberID` property/row and I want to retrieve every `unique` value inside that row.

In other word, I want to retrieve non-repeated `jabberID` values from my `Message` model. Can anyone help out figuring this?

The way I use to do with coredata was using `returnsDistinctResults` setting on the `NSFetchRequest`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found out Realm doesn't fully support distinct queries yet. The good news is I also found a workaround for it, on this [github issue](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1103).

**Objective-c**

```
RLMResults *messages = [Message allObjects];
NSMutableArray *uniqueIDs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *uniqueMessages  = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (Message *msg in messages) {
    NSString *jabberID = msg.jabberID;
    Message *uniqueMSG = (Message *)msg;
    if (![uniqueIDs containsObject:jabberID]) {
        [uniqueMessages addObject:uniqueMSG];
        [uniqueIDs addObject:jabberID];
    }
}
```

**Swift 3.0**

```
let realm = try! Realm()
let distinctIDs = Set(realm.objects(Message.self).value(forKey: "jabberID") as! [String])
var distinctMessages = [Message]()
for jabberID in distinctIDs {
    if let message = realm.objects(Message.self).filter("jabberID = '\(jabberID)'").first {
        distinctMessages.append(message)
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `allObjects` return a `Results` collection?

Comment: Yes, it will return a Results collection of all the objects.

Comment: I see, then this approach will loose the lazy evaluation from `Results`.

Comment: you shoud use a set to check membership, is much faster

Answer (score 13):

Functional programming approach since Swift has it, and Realm lazy loads;  Not as easy/available a solution in Objective-C but for Swift at least:
**Swift**

```
let distinctTypes = reduce(Realm().objects(User), []) { $0 + (!contains($0, $1.type) ? [$1.type] : [] ) }
```

***UPDATED:***

Swift reduce is kind of a performance intensive, allocating a bunch of intermediate array's, instead the following should be much better performance wise, but must be explicitly cast

```
let distinctTypes = Array(Set(Realm().objects(User).valueForKey("type") as! [String]))
```