# Realm GROUP BY query

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

I've searched a lot but can't find any documantation or an example for GROUP BY queries.

For now, even putting RLMResults in a loop can solve my problem but is there an elegant way to get?

Comment: On July 2014 same question has already answered by a group member. I think still need to solve by manually.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/realm-cocoa/group/realm-cocoa/NRcYJNtrvd0/XOTcVCwUfV8J

Answer (score 1):

It was discussed [at the Java group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/realm-java/5KsLCxQTcd0) and also applies for the iOS implementation.

> Nov 2014
>
> GROUP BY is only interesting in combination with some kind of
>   aggregate function. We have the most common ones directly on
>   RealmResults, like sum(), average(), max() and min(), are these what
>   you are looking for or do you have something else in mind?
>
> We actually implemented DISTINCT but found some bugs that needed to be
>   fixed before it can be released. So hopefully really soon :)

The distinct operation is yet not available but there is [an easy workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30246541/1476885) for it.

> Oct 2015
>
> DISTINCT made progress in core, but isn't yet fully implemented and
>   wasn't so exposed yet neither in the Java binding nor in any other.
>   We're working on that and will make sure to report back here once we
>   have something to test out.

Regarding examples, the [official docs](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/) have one:

> The aggregate expressions @count, @min, @max, @sum and @avg are
>   supported on RLMArray properties, e.g.
>   `[Company objectsWhere:@"employees.@count > 5"]` to find all companies with more
>   than five employees.

Comment: How to use @max for, for example, id